# extra white space between tables in html email for gmail client

Tags: html, css, html-email

My code is at

http://jsfiddle.net/user1212/G86KE/4/

The problem is in gmail it leaves an extra white space between 2 tables inside the same cell.
I have tried `display:block;  margin:0; padding:0; line-height:0;`

However , it does not seem to go away.

[image]

Is there a fix to this?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post the full code with the images also (i.e. make the image paths absolute)?

Comment: Have you tried adding 'border-spacing: 0;' to the style as well? That should hopefully do it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The updated jsfiddle with the code and images is at http://jsfiddle.net/user1212/G86KE/4/

Comment: border-spacing:0; did not help to remove the space between 2 tables inside the same cell <td><table></table><table></table></td>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Styling HTML mails is horrible.

A few tips:

`border-spacing:0; /*this should fix the spacing problem*/`

You need to apply this to all the tables you are using, so you should include it in a `<style>` block at the top like so:

```
<head>
  <style>
    table {border-spacing: 0;}
  </style>
</head>
```

(sorry for the bad formatting, somehow the code refused to show up properly on multiple lines)

Comment: In my case, it does not fix the space :(

Comment: Are you using padding or margin on the cells? That could also be the problem. Basically try to scale down the problem as much as possible - just use a simple table (with minimal styling) and see if you can fix it, then increment and see where the problem arises.

Comment: You can't use style tags in the head, it only works with some emails.

Answer (score 16):

Using style="display:block" in the image tag should work. Also, *don't forget* to add it to the spacer image if you're using that.

Comment: Thanks Hannah. This one worked for me. Adding a style tag to all the images affected.

Comment: The user asks about spaces in a table which has no images.  This would not be the accepted answer in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not what you might be looking for but,...
Loose the spacer (spacer.gif), in order to loose the big spaces in a responsive email images has to be embedded in one cell per row, than will display all images block-ed.
Hope it helps, this was the solution I used in my case.
One cell per row:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="image.jpg" width="600" height="300" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `style="line-height:50%"` onto the `<table>`. You will notice that this will affect the text line heights if you have text in your mailer. To fix this you will then have to add: `style="line-height:100%"` to the `<td>` with text.

Comment: This may be an issue in gmail even if there is no text in the table. I spent a few days trying to work out what the problem was, and `line-height` was it. +1

Answer (score 2):

So I know this may seem a little wild, but I had the exact same issue and it turned out to be the brs in my code. Yes, the fact that I formatted my HTML by nesting my tds resulted in gmail adding new tds with br tags inside.

It took me time to realize that we were converting the email header and footer code to text before appending it to our emails.

If you're using a similar approach I would suggest "minifying" your HTML.

Instead of:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Content
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Try:

```
<table><tr><td>Content</td></tr></table>
```

As horrid as it may seem.

Comment: This is the answer for me. +1 I was seeing phantom <tr> and <td> with empty <p>'s inside them being added to tables by gmail. I found this comment and tried 'minifying' my HTML and it worked like a charm!

Comment: I'm so glad it worked! I usually respond to questions from 2-4 years ago so my solutions are rarely helpful to the OP :P

Answer (score 1):

`display:block` worked great for the gap problem between my body and footer, but it didn't do anything for my header; neither did the other fixes. I know this is an old thread, but in case anyone stumbles across it and the above didn't help, this did it for me:

Add `style="line-height:1px; font-size:0.0em;"` to the `<td>` tag which contains your header table.

You might have to try a couple of different tags to find the right one, but it's another solution to try.

Answer (score 1):

Besides adding `display:block` to your `img` also add `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"` to your `table` (important: do not forget applying this to your wrapping `table` as well)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well, I noticed the header's and body's content are actually tables inside another cell. Why don't you try to separate the header and body and move them on their separated row?

Something like this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <!-- Header table -->
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
       <!-- Body table -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, just a tip, don't use `<center>` tag to center stuff. If you're inside a table cell, just use `align="center"`. This, also, applies to the whole table, so in order to center a table, just set the `align` property to `center`.

Comment: Why do you not use the `<center>` tag?

Comment: Some of the clients are not really render it. I'm referring to webkit based clients(iOS mainly). This is based on my experience, so I might be wrong.
Also, `<center>` is better used for text not elements.

Comment: For CSS, `margin:0 auto;text-align:center` and then for HTML, `align="center"` And then DIV and Center wrap with further CENTER aligned fixes. This ensures it working. W3 Validation is no longer of importance for many sites - it is a guideline.

Comment: Divs?! In HTML emails? Not sure that you really looked into this part of HTML coding.

Comment: We use DIVs that if not supported by device, email client or browser, the user falls back to the TABLE coding. Our emails our complex with TABLELESS rules, semantic markup and also responsive queries. We therefore get all clients and devices - as many as we can. Emails are a complex task often when designing to some PSD requirements. There are always hacks and ifs and loops - not one simple way more or less the time in 7 years of experience son.

Comment: I use `<divs>` all the time in email coding to great effect.  I also use `<center>` all the time to great effect.  You still need to use tables.  I no longer use `<align="center">` because it's impossible to override it for responsive behaviour, and it also means the tables don't stack up next to each other.  Sorry xnamex, I think TheBlackBenzKid probably looked into things more than you give him/her credit for.

Answer (score -2):

simply add

```
table{ 
font-size:0em;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

it will solve your problem