# Need to eliminate space between two adjacent tables

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I'm trying to create an email template. I'm having trouble finding the answer to two remaining issues.

1. I can't seem to eliminate the white space between three tables that are Not nested. I want them right on top of each other.

   I already looked at this post and a bunch of other's but fail to find anything that works:  [extra white space between tables in html email for gmail client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689800/extra-white-space-between-tables-in-html-email-for-gmail-client)
2. in the middle white table to contain the text, I haven't found a way to eliminate the border shading on the right and bottom of the table.  I need the border around it but want it to have a consistent color.

I've looked at posts that say to use the following but that didn't help.

```
<style type="text/css">
    table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
  </style>
```

Below is the actual code and I appreciate any input others can provide.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <table style="height: 19px; background-color: #f3a601; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" width="600">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td style="width: 588px;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://static.mago.co/6e47bc6a7def11e193654040b5df84c1/Media/CKM_email_template_banner_with_Mr_F.png" alt="" width="584" height="118" /></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <br />
      <table style="width: 600px; border-color: #f3a601; background-color: #ffffff; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="5px">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td style="border: 2px solid #ffffff;">&nbsp;This is just a test.<br /><br />TEsting.<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <br />
      <table style="height: 78px; background-color: #f3a601; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" width="600">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td style="width: 590px;">
                  <table style="width: 590px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Connect With Us!</span></td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <br />
                  <table style="width: 590px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr style="text-align: center;">
                           <td><span style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/comedykidsmagic" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Facebook</a><br /><img src="http://static.mago.co/6e47bc6a7def11e193654040b5df84c1/Media/Facebook.png" alt="Facebook icon" width="25" height="25" /><br /></span></td>
                           <td><span style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/comedykidsmagic" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Twitter</a><br /><img src="http://static.mago.co/6e47bc6a7def11e193654040b5df84c1/Media/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter icon" width="25" height="25" /><br /></span></td>
                           <td><span style="font-size: 12px;">Google Plus<br /><img src="http://static.mago.co/6e47bc6a7def11e193654040b5df84c1/Media/Google_.png" alt="Google+ icon" width="25" height="25" /><br /></span></td>
                           <td><span style="font-size: 12px;">YouTube<br /><img src="http://static.mago.co/6e47bc6a7def11e193654040b5df84c1/Media/YouTube.png" alt="YouTube icon" width="25" height="25" /><br /></span></td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">` given this is for html email also delete the `br` between `table`s

Comment: Dippas, thanks for the quick reply.  Deleting the </br> fixed the table spacing issue. Thanks again.